# Can't run Python's mapscript because of a missing DLL

Tags: python, import, path, mapserver

I have been trying to run an undocumented backend which used to work but now it does not, it is supposed to use mapserver and mapscript, I keep trying to send it a post call but I keep getting this error

```
File "C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mapscript\mapscript.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _mapscript
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
172.16.31.175 - - [29/Mar/2024 04:15:55] "POST /backendapi HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

According to the library documentation this pops up when you try to run it without setting up the enviroment path access to MapServer.dll, here's the thing, I have installed MapServer twice now and I just can't find this file, it's not anywhere in the directory I've checked. I tried setting the path to search in my apache server's bin but nope (The apache server created by MS4W, my MapServer installation). As you might notice I have python 3.7 right now, I tried downgrading to check if maybe it worked for pre 3.8 (path changes) but nope. Do you know of any particular MapServer installation that can give me access to this MapServer.dll, I'm losing my mind over this.

I would also be fine if you suggested alternatives to mapscript so I can bypass this issue